# $\tilde \phi:\Gamma (W)\rightarrow \Gamma(V)$ may not extends to all $k(W)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, plane-curves

A problem from Fulton's Algebraic Curves:--

Let $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ be a polynomial map between two affine varieties and $\tilde \phi:\Gamma (W)\rightarrow \Gamma(V)$ be the induced map between co-ordinate rings.Let $P\in V$ and $\phi(P)=Q$. Show that $\tilde \phi$ extends to a unique ring homorphism from $\mathscr O_Q(W)$ to $\mathscr O_P(V)$. **Note that $\tilde \phi$ may not extends to all $k(W)$**.

My problem is the following : $\tilde \phi:\Gamma(W)\rightarrow \Gamma(V)$ is a ring homorphism between two integral domains and $k(W),k(V)$ are their fields of fractions, so that $\tilde \phi$ can be extended to a field homorphism from $k(W)$ to $k(V)$. Also, $\mathscr O_Q(W)\subseteq k(W)$ and $\mathscr O_P(V)\subseteq k(V)$. So the line written in bold means to say, $\tilde \phi:\Gamma(W)\rightarrow \Gamma(V)$ cannot be extended to a homeomophism from $k(W)$ to $\mathscr O_P(V)$. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line written in bold says that you can't in general extend the morphism $\tilde{\phi}:\Gamma(W)\rightarrow \Gamma(V)$ to a morphism $\psi:K(W)\rightarrow K(V)$. So in order to solve the problem you just have to given an example in which it can't be extended.

There are two reasons why the map shouldn't extend in general.

1. **Algebraic reason:**

   The universal property of localization tells you the following:
   Given a morphism of rings $f:A\rightarrow B$ and a multiplicative
   system $S\subseteq A$. The map $f$ extentends to a morphism
   $\tilde{f}:S^{-1}A\rightarrow B$ if and only if $f(s)$ is invertible
   in $B$ for each $s\in S$.

   When $B$ is a field this translate to $f(s)\neq 0$ for every $s\in
   S$ and when $S=A\setminus\{0\}$ this translate to $f$ being
   injective. And in general the map $\tilde{\phi}$ is not necessarily
   injective.
2. **Geometric reason:**

   The idea is that $K(W)$ is the set of polynomial functions defined
   over some dense open set in $W$ with values in $k$, and the map $K(W)\rightarrow K(V)$
   will be given by precomposition with $\phi: V\rightarrow W$, that is: 
   $$\begin{align} K(W)&\rightarrow K(V) \\ f&\mapsto f\circ \phi \end{align}$$ Hence if the image of $\phi$ is too small then maybe the composition $f\circ \phi$ is not possible because $\text{Im}(\phi)\cap \text{Dom}(f)$ could be empty and there is nothing to compose. For example if $\text{Im}(\phi)$ is a dense set this will never happen.

Finally it happens that $\phi$ has dense image iff $\tilde{\phi}$ is injective and in both cases you can extend the map. But in general neither of this two things happen.

Take for example $V=\mathbb{A}^1$ and $W=\{a\}\in \mathbb{A}^1$. Then the constant map $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ sending everything to $a$ doesn't extend because the map between rings is $$\begin{align} \tilde{\phi}:k[x]&\rightarrow k\\ p(x)&\mapsto p(a)
\end{align}$$ and it is not injective.